# Realtek rtl8192cu-fixes issue elementary os

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers

I asked this question here[https://askubuntu.com/questions/594760/realtek-rtl8192cu-fixes-issue-elementary-os] but was redirect to this site.

Copy of original questions

Has anyone had any luck with the fixed drivers for the rtl 8192cu chipset?

I followed this one my ubuntu install and it worked perfectly https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes

However when I try this on EOS after reboot the usb dongle light won't come on. It feels like I blacklisted the old driver but for some reason the new one isn't loaded
If I `lsusb` I can see the device but `rfkill list all` shows nothing related to wifi.
Any help would be hugely appreciated as without this the wireless connection is unusable.
Thanks in advance

Follow up after this. I did what was said in the answer in the link, this just seemed to re-enable the old driver

I have also updated to the Freya beta as the driver is only meant to work on ubuntu 13 and above or something. Same install process, same issues

Again, any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not entirely sure what I did or why I did it. I clean installed and went through the install process, after reboot I just ran the install again out of interested and it installed again which I thought was odd so I rebooted again and now it works.

I'm not sure if this is a fix for everyone and god knows why it's happened (maybe someone of higher knowledge can fill me in) but it doesn't hurt to try if you are having the same error.